# Moving Hive table from HDFS to Amazon Redshift

Tags: r, hadoop, hive, amazon-redshift

I try to transfer a Hive table created by joining 4-5 data sets to Redshift. How should this process be implemented?

We have R available on edge node. The Hive table has to be transferred to S3 first and from s3 to Redshift. Is this the only method?

Is it possible to use R, i.e. move my data set from HDFS to R using RHive package and then move this data set from R to Redshift?

Answer (score 0):

You can use RJDBC to connect to Redshift( Redshift is pgsql). So you can use read a row from hive, and load it to Redshift using RJDBC from R.

You create batch of 1000 or more and insert in Redshift.

If you are doing insert method , then create your table in redhshift using encoding type for each column.

The load data to s3 and then copy form s3 works faster than insert commands. copy will apply compression(encoding) by default .

So i suggest you use load to s3 from HDFS and then copy command.